# I Have Error in my Schema Workbanch, How To Fix It?

Tags: schema, olap-cube, workbench

the table on my dimension can't be read and it shows a cross on the dimension.
how to fix it?

`piture all`[all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh1kV.png)
`pituret dimension`[dimension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z64qm.png)
`piture hierarchy`[hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztfHv.png)
`piture table`[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIzm8.png)

I have tried to replace it with the database that I created recently, but the result is still the same